# How to use \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl without self signed certificate

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am consuming API in magento 2 using

> \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl

Its working with http but not working with https so I am getting following error.

`SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate`

So how to **disable SSL verification** using Curl class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After research I found the method name `setOption` in Class

> \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl

And add following line in my code like this

```
$curl = new \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl;

$curl->setOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
$curl->setOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
```

And it works :)